# WIF Signout from within the Identity Provider

Tags: wif

Is it possible to sign out from a relying party from within the Identity provider without calling the RP?

I've implemented a custom STS in MVC that issues Claims to an RP on sign in, and my sign out logic within the IP works when making a standard sign out request:

```
 // Process signout request
 SignOutRequestMessage signOutRequestMessage = (SignOutRequestMessage)WSFederationMessage.CreateFromUri(Request.Url);
 // get response to invoke signout
 HttpResponse signOutResponse = new HttpResponse(HttpContext.Response.Output);
```

However, this code does not work when I attempt to do the same from within the IP.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}://{1}/PassiveSTS?wa=wsignout1.0",request.Url.Scheme,request.Url.Host));
// Process signout request
SignOutRequestMessage signOutRequestMessage = (SignOutRequestMessage)WSFederationMessage.CreateFromUri(uri);
// get response to invoke signout
HttpResponse signOutResponse = new HttpResponse(context.Response.Output);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your RP validates the issued token the RP will establish it's own auth session with a new cookie, which the IP has no control over. Typically, the RP handles it's own signout by clearing this cookie, SessionAuthenitcationModule.SignOut() does this.

But if you want your IP to end the RP session I think you would have to do it with a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

To safely support federated sign-out you should sign-out from both the identity provider and the relying party application.

Each Identity provider is different with regards the persistence of auth cookies and you need to understand how Fed-Signout is handled by your IDP (STS).

More information can be found here for ADFS:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx

If you wanted to cheat this process you could ensure that the STS and Application are on the same domain and configure the cookie domain to be the same (using wildcard cookies).

Answer (score -1):

We need to do below to signOut from RP and IDP

var fedModule =  FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

fedModule.SignOut(true);
Response.Redirect(new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(fedModule.Issuer), fedModule.Realm).WriteQueryString());

Comment: This worked for me, cheers. The construction of that identity provider signout url is not obvious.